# How redirect wrong querystring to custom errorpage + 404 status

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to redirect users that use a wrong querystring in the URL to a custom error page while ALSO giving a 404 status through the .htaccess directive

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/404.php
```

> > EDIT: this does not give 404 but 302!!!  The "http://www.domain.com"
> >     causes a redirect. Just the local path gives a 404. See also http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

Therefore I made a script in the request-receiving index.php that determines if the querystring is not valid and if so, gives this command:

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

BUT this does not redirect via the .htaccess directive ErrorDocument but just gives a 404 status to the visitor.

And when using `header("Location: 404.php")` you get a 302 status, and when using `header("Location: 404.php", true, 404)` the status is 404 but it does not go to the custom 404.php page.

Now I use

```
header ("Location: ", true, 404); 
echo "The URL you use doesn't lead to an existing page, etc.";
```

But this was not the original plan... How would I make users that use a wrong querystring in the URL redirect to the custom error page while also giving a 404 status through the .htaccess directive ErrorDocument, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware the only way to show the 404 page from PHP is to explicitly redirect to it.  The reason is Apache (or whatever web server you're using) has already successfully located a resource to which to direct the client (the PHP script being executed).  If the PHP script can't resolve the client's request then it has to handle the sending of 404 headers and displaying the page itself.

You could either redirect

```
header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header ('Location: http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/404.php');
```

Or you could include the 404 page into the PHP script that wants to trigger a 404.

```
header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
include ('/path/to/404.php');
```

EDIT: If you use the first technique (redirection) and want to pass the $_GET to the script so it can determine what's wrong with it, you can do this.

```
header ("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
header ('Location: http://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . '/404.php?' . http_build_query ($_GET));
```

If you include the 404.php file then the $_GET will be available to it already

Comment: You can actually use rewriterule to return [R=404] like you would 301/302 redirects in htaccess, but it sounds like the invalid querystring logic would best be handled in php. But if ErrorDocument 404 is properly defined (and allowed) in htaccess a php 404 header should be sufficient to display the custom error page pointed to in htaccess ErrorDocument

Comment: I have just tried that to make sure, PHP doesn't redirect to the 404 page if you just send a 404 header.  You have to deal with it yourself.

Comment: I suspected already my plan was not possible because the .htaccess is not passed again by the request, for the resource is located by the PHP script being executed. Your last suggestion looked like a good one to me, but when I look in the access.log, the status is not 404 but 302, it just skips the first header command it seems.
@webchemist: In the .htaccess I cannot check if the querystring is valid because the pages come from a database and the regex in the .htaccess cannot be build from retrieving the right values to compare.

Comment: You're right I was remembering wrong... but you cannot redirect using location header, it will come back 302

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189169/redirect-to-404-page-or-display-404-message

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution to show a custom 404 page and get status 404 using header refresh:

```
header("refresh:0;url=/404.php",TRUE,404);
```

However this is not standard behavior because you are actually redirecting the user to www.domain.com/404.php instead of showing the 404 page under the bad url (like www.domain.com/index.php?q=badrequest) like Apache ErrorDocument would, although I'm not sure it would matter to search engine spiders since the original url still returned a 404 response...

Also for anyone coming across this curious about the htaccess 404 redirect mentioned in Gordon's answer comments, you would use it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(match conditions)$ - [R=404,NC,L]
```