# Need to block everyone except for me on my PHP file

Tags: php, css, ip, block, whitelist

I need to block everyone except for me on my PHP file. I can't give you the link to it, for the reason it's classified and has important info.

I have a PHP file and need to be the only person to be able to access the URL and view it. I also want to have a 404 page come up for other people who try and go to the URL.

My site is http://www.unfedzombie.tk/ - I'm getting good hosting very soon! If you go to my site you'll automatically go to a blocked page to check out my site then well really there's no need I don't have much on it yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use .htaccess with .htpasswd, it is very easy.
This tutorial may help you: http://weavervsworld.com/docs/other/passprotect.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['allowed'])){

//Whole page code here


} else {
header('Location: YOUR 404 PAGE LINK HERE') ;
}
```

Apply this code to with your restricted page

& make new php file for authenting yourself
and put this code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['password'])  && $_POST['password'] == 'YOUR_DESIRED_PASSWORD'){
$_SESSION['allowed'] = true;
header('Location: YOUR_BLOCKED_PAGE_URL_HERE') ;
}
?>
<center><form method="post" action="">Password : <input type="password" name="password"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></form></center>
```

hope you wanted the same

Comment: Nope, i did everything and im getting a syntax parse error on the page i want to block i did make the auth page but it still aint working

Comment: Its saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: I get the error on my very top start of all my page coding (html)

Comment: lol i just gave up on it its just pissing me off to be honest but i have a new question up try and answer it if you could thanks

Comment: @Ankit: +1, although there's no need to `echo` HTML. Just exit PHP mode and then use HTML normally - much more readable!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to turn off Apache.

However, if you need access to it via the Internet, I suggest you implement a password form on another php/html file that sets a $_SESSION variable ("access"?) when you enter the password correctly, then redirects to your PHP file. In your PHP file, use 'if (isset($_SESSION["access"]))' before displaying the rest of the page. If it's not set, simply use 'header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); exit;' to display the 404 page to the user.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189169/redirect-to-404-page-or-display-404-message) to find out how to do a 404 header.

Then to show this to everyone but you find your IP address by googling "what is my ip" and then have your PHP reject anyone who is not this address by replacing 255.255.255.255 with your IP address below

```
 if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '255.255.255.255'){/*INSERT 404 REDIRECT CODE*/ die();}
```

You will have to update your code whenever your ISP changes your IP unless you have a static address.

Technically this is enough to do what you asked, but to be fully secure you should web search how to create a PHP user authentication system with sessions to fully secure your data. This is a VERY well documented subject on this forum and innumerable other places on the web so I will not go into it, but by doing the above you can make PHP only show YOU the login form and redirect anyone else to the 404 error page.

Comment: ip's can be spoofed, ip's can be shared, this is a bad idea

Comment: Thats why I recommended using sessions as well (sessions + IP restrictions) > (sessions + no IP restrictions)