# Showing Error 404 when needed data is missing

Tags: php

I have a page that depends on MySQL Data. If a row its looking for does not exist, I want to show an error 404.

I already did something like this

Note:
   $data = is the query result

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($data);

if($count==0) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
} else {
    //Do Nothing
}
```

The $count does return a 0 value.

Nothing's Happening :C Help pls

Comment: what are you expecting to happen? what you have will just update the header to a `404` but the page will display normally.

Comment: If you are expecting a page to come back, it won't happen unless you tell it a page that you want to display. If you look at your chrome console, you might be able to see the 404 in there.

Comment: You can just show some error instead of 404. You should only use 404 when it's an actual page on your server or an URL that doesn't exist.

Comment: most easiest way is design a 404 page and redirect to that page. related SO reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189169/redirect-to-404-page-or-display-404-message